# Log of a product of characteristic functions (Lindeberg's theorem and Accompanying Laws theorem)

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Perhaps this question is very specific to the book '*Probability Theory*' by Varadhan.

I'm trying to understand the proofs of Lindeberg's Theorem and the Accompanying Laws Theorem. The setup for both of these is that we are trying to find a limiting distribution of a sequence of random variables
$$
Z_1 = X_{1,1} + \dots + X_{1,k_1}\\
Z_2 = X_{2,1} + \dots + \dots + X_{2,k_2}\\
\vdots\\
Z_n = X_{2,1} + \dots + \dots + \dots + X_{n,k_n}\\
\vdots
$$
with some assumptions about independence and uniform infinitesimality of the $X_{n,j}$. Let $\phi_{n,j}$ denote the characteristic function of each $X_{n,j}$. The book then makes some estimates and computations for the product
$$\hat{\mu}_n = \prod\limits_j \phi_{n,j}.
$$
(Note this is the characteristic function of $Z_n$.) One of these computations, see the bottom of page 51 and again the top of page 56, involves taking the log of this product and using $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$. However, in general, I feel that there needs to be some justification for this. We are taking the log of a product of complex numbers. If the arguments add up to a large angle, the expression $$\log\left(\prod a_i\right) = \sum\log(a_i)$$ doesn't seem to be valid anymore. (We might have to add some multiple of $2\pi$, right?)

I hope someone can clarify my misunderstanding here. Perhaps by providing a justification that I missed. Additionally, I have noticed that in another book (Billingsley), the use of logs is avoided in the proof of Lindeberg's theorem. But I find it frustrating to change books and notation. And further, I don't see the Accompanying Laws theorem in Billingsley.

Thanks for reading and apologies for the wall of text.

**Edit:** The proofs I'm referring to can be found in some [notes](https://www.math.nyu.edu/%7Evaradhan/course/PROB.ch3.pdf) from the author's website. Theorems 3.18 and 3.19.

Comment: I don't have the book in front of me, but I'd assume the uniform infinitesimality of the summands translates into approximations like $\log\phi = \log(1+\epsilon)\approx\epsilon$ and so on, saving the day.

Comment: For fixed $t$, $\phi_{n,j}(t) \to 1$ as $n\to \infty$. But we're multiplying $k_n$ of such things together? Each one is close to $1$, but there are many of them. Is that not an issue?

Comment: Of course there is an issue, but because there is a theorem, I assume the issue can be overcome.  Without the proof in front of me, I can't speculate further.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Two comments: the 2nd and 3d displayed equations on p.73, I think, bear out what I've commented above.  And when taking logarithms of characteristic functions we always use the branch such that $\log \phi(t)$ is continuous in $t$ and consistent with $\log\phi(0)=0$.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd equations are clear to me (he proves them later using the infinitesimality as you suggest). I'm slightly confused by your requirement on the branch of $\log$. For example, if $\phi$ comes from a Gaussian perhaps, couldn't $\phi(t)$ spiral around the origin? In practice, to define the log of a non-vanishing holomorphic function, we need a simply connected domain. And the function $z$ vanishes at $0$.

Comment: For characteristic functions, $\phi(0)=1$, not $\phi(0)=0$.  The characteristic function of $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is $t\mapsto \exp(it\mu-\sigma^2t^2/2)$; the version of the logarithm we use is $t\mapsto it\mu-\sigma^2t^2/2$ which is (1) continuous, (2) vanishes at the origin, and (3) has the property that $\exp$ of it is the characteristic function.

Comment: Given a characteristic function $\phi$, can you please define carefully your function $\log$ (which depends on $\phi$)?

Comment: Instead of arguing with me, why don't you spend your time studying your text.  If you have a question of form "why does equation k follow from k-1" I might think about it, and possibly try to help you.

Comment: The question is how the 5th equation follows from the 4th on page 73 of the notes. I genuinely do not understand what you mean when you say 'log' as above. If it helps, my definition of 'log' is the function defined on $\mathbb{C} \smallsetminus \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ by $\log(z) := \int\limits_{1}^z dw/w$ (this is independent of the path). One can see that by this definition, $e^{\log z} = z$ and $\log(re^{i\theta}) = \log(r) + i\theta$ for $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: The second 'log' in the equation above is the real logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, of what the logarithm of a characteristic function is, is addressed in Eugene Lukas's *Characteristic Functions*:

> We have shown that every characteristic function $f(t)$ is continuous and that $f(0)=1$.  Therefore there exists a neighbourhood of the origin in which $f(t)$ is different from zero; let $|t|<\Delta$ be this neighborhood. The function $\phi(t)=\log f(t)$ can be defined uniquely for $|t|<\Delta$, provided we understand by $\log f(t)$ the principal branch of the logarithm of the characteristic function, i.e. that determination of $\log f(t)$ which is continuous and vanished at $t=0$.  (p.26 in 2nd edition of 1970.)

It is true that in general, for $z\in\mathbb C{\setminus}\{0\}$, the value of the integral $\int_\gamma \frac {du}u$ depends on the path $\gamma$ connecting $1$ to $z$. But in the context of Varahdan's proof,  the rule stated by Lukacs saves the day.  If a characteristic function $f$ does not vanish anywhere on $[-T,T]$, there is a *unique* continuous function $\ell(t)$ on $[-T,T]$ such that $\exp(\ell(t))=f(t)$ on $[-T,T]$ for which $\ell(0)=0$.  We  then *define* $\log f$ to be that $\ell$.  This amounts to using the contour $\gamma:[0,t]\to\mathbb C{\setminus}\{0\}$,  connecting $1$ to $f(t)$, given by $\gamma(u)=f(u)$ on $[0,t]$, in the formula $\log f(t) = \int_\gamma \frac{du}u$.  Since  all the characteristic functions in Varadhan's proof are differentiable,  this takes the form: $$\log f(t) = \int_0^t \frac {f'(u)}{f(u)}du.$$

If $g$ is another characteristic function that also does not vanish anywhere on $[-T,T]$, and $h=fg$, this convention allows us to conclude $\log h = \log f + \log g$, because for each $t\in[-T,T]$, $$\exp(\log h(t))=h(t)=f(t)g(t)=\exp(\log f(t))\exp(\log g(t)) = \exp(\log f(t)+\log g(t))\tag{L},$$ and because the sum of the two continuous functions $\log f(t)$ and $\log g(t)$ is continuous.

Here is how this fits in Varadhan's argument. There are characteristic function $\phi_{n,j}(t)$ and $\hat\mu_n=\prod_{j=1}^n\phi_{n,j}$, and other functions $\psi_{n,j}$ such that $\psi_{n,j}(t)=\exp[\phi_{n,j}(t)-1]$, and $\psi_n=\prod_{j=1}^n \psi_{n,j}$. It is supposed that for each finite $T$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{|t|\le T} \sup_{1\le j\le n}|\phi_{n,j}(t)-1|=0\tag{H1}$$
and
$$\sup_n\sup_{|t|\le T}|\phi_{n,j}(t)-1|<\infty \tag{H2}.$$
Varahdan starts a long chain of deductions from these, the first of which
puzzles the OP: ``this would imply that'':
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{|t|\le T}|\log \hat\mu_n(t)-\log\psi_n(t)|\le
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{|t|\le T}\sum_{j=1}^n|\log \phi_{n,j}(t)-[\phi_{n,j}(t)-1]|...$$

Here is why this first step follows.  Note that for given $T$, for all $n$ sufficiently large, we have $|\phi_{n,j}(t)-1|\le 1/2$ on $[-T,T]$, so all the functions in sight are non-vanishing on $[-T,T]$, and the  recipe (L) tells us that $\log\hat\mu_n(t)=\sum_j \log\phi_{n,j}(t)$, and $\log\psi_n(t)=\sum_j \log \psi_{n,j}(t)$.  (Note that  the $\psi_{n,j}$ and $\psi_n$ are also characteristic functions, non vanishing on $[-T,T]$, so (L) applies to them, too.)  So we have
$$\begin{align*}\left|\log \hat\mu_n(t)-\log\psi_n(t)\right| &= \left|\sum_{j=1}^n \log\phi_{n,j}(t) - \sum_{j=1}^n \log\psi_{n,j}(t)\right|\\&\le \sum_{j=1}^n \left|\log\phi_{n,j}(t)- \log\psi_{n,j}(t)\right|=\sum_{j=1}^n \left|\log\phi_{n,j}(t)-[\phi_{n,j}(t)-1]\right|\end{align*}$$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you! Will go through.

Comment: I understand what you have written, but out of curiosity, what is Lukacs talking about? What if the characteristic function is not differentiable?

Comment: The bit of Lukacs I quoted is from Chapter 1, the definitions, notation, basic properties chapter.  Later on he uses the log of the c.f. when discussing infinitely divisible and stable distributions, as in section 3.8 of Varadhran's book.  An analogous discussion is in Feller. v.2, about 1/2 thru the book.  If the c.f. $f$  is not differentiable the easy formula $\log f(t)=\int_0^t f'/f$ goes away, but the existence of a unique continuous lift of the image of $f$ under the covering map $z\mapsto\exp(z)$ still holds.

Comment: Oh, right. Should of known.